# How to get entered content in summernote editor using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I have used the Summernote editor. I am able to get the editor but I am unable to get the data entered in the editor.

I have followed instructions in [this url](https://summernote.org/getting-started/#get--set-code) but I am unable to get the entered data in the editor while clicking button. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
  tabsize: 2,
  height: 100
});

$("#test").click(function() {
  var markupStr = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
  alert(markupStr);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
<div id="summernote"></div>
<div> <button id="test">click</button> </div>
```

Comment: Working fine here

Comment: I placed your code in to an executable snippet where it appears to work fine. Check your console for errors, and ensure you're running your jQuery code *after* the DOM has loaded, ie. in a document.ready event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#summernote').summernote({
  tabsize: 2,
  height: 100
});

$("#test").click(function() {
  var markupStr = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
  alert(markupStr);
});
});
```

Comment: Have you add all js in head tag? Can you add whole html in your question?